# Persistence in an external database of mysql using Mosquitto

Tags: android, database, persistence, mosquitto

When I confige the mosquitto.conf file I can implement the persistence with the default mosquitto.db ,but it can't satisfy our need,so I would like to implement the persistence in the external database of mysql ,although I add the code in the mosquitto.conf as follows:

```
db_host 127.0.0.1
db_name test
db_username root
db_password 123456
```

I can not still succeed, I don't know  whether I config the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not currently possible to use anything other than the built in persistence with mosquitto.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below Authentication Plugin for Mosquitto Whiccan be used with MySQL , CDB, SQLite3 database, Redis key/value store and TLS PSK.

https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug